# How to install a peek on Artful?

Tags: snap, 17.10

I want to install Peek. I searched in sofware and clicked the install button. After downloading an enormous file it crashed moaning about some problem with snap -- unfortunately I missed that error. Then it said peek was already installed (but it wasn't).

I tried running peek from the terminal, and got this:

```
~$ peek
You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install gnome-3-24
snap connect peek:gnome-3-24-platform gnome-3-24:gnome-3-24-platform
```

Really? I have to manage my own dependencies? I tried running the suggested command with 3.26

```
$ snap install gnome-3-26
error: snap "gnome-3-26" not found
```

I then found I could remove snap from the command line with `snap remove peek`, so I did that. I tried Software install again, this time it seemed to succeed and gave me a Launch button. Which does nothing.

I tried to run from the commandline and got the same error about needing to connect snapd to gnome.

Comment: Presumably it's `gnome-3-26` with a hyphen instead of a period, going by the suggestions.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the snap package to work. However there is a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install peek
```

...and as a bonus (1) it works, (2) it's 128kB to download not 56MB! *With apt, it's a snap!*

Comment: I'm getting an error. `~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~peek-developers/ubuntu/stable'.
The team named '~peek-developers' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/stable'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'daily':  Peek daily builds
 * 'stable':  Peek stable releases`

Comment: Tried it after 5 mins opening another terminal, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has changed since the original post, platform snaps for gnome apps are now installed and connected automatically ... details are in the snap forum at https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/auto-connection-for-gnome-3-24-content-interface/1379

Comment: Hmmm. just re tried that (on an uptodate 17.10). Peek installs but won't run, with the same error as in my OP.